# Упал sql-сервер

Tags: sql-server

Писал запросы в Managment Studio, выполнил команду shytdown with nowait. После этого сервер перестал соединяться с ядром. Выдаёт ошибку, представленную на картинке. Вопрос, что делать? Так уже было, переустановил недавно, но вот опять. Не вечно же переустанавливать. Мб было у кого ?  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась так: диспетчер задач -> службы -> MSSQLSERVER -> ПКМ -> запустить